# Form de agendamento com vários itens que precisam ser alugados ao mesmo tempo

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

[image: Imagem do form]

Preciso fazer uma agenda que cadastre:

- As informações do agendamento
- Cadastre vários instrumentos de uma vez só com as informações do agendamento

O botão `Buscar cliente` puxa os dados(ID Cliente e Nome)de uma tabela de cadastro de clientes, assim como o botão `buscar instrumento` que puxa apenas o campo `Codigo` instrumento de uma tabela de instrumentos.

Em baixo do botão `buscar instrumentos` tem um `dgv`, nesse `dgv` eu queria colocar todos os instrumentos que seriam alugados em um agendamento, e depois quando clicado o botão `agendar`, um cadastro nos dois `dgvs` ao lado seriam feitos, o `dgv` de AGENDAMENTOS teria todas as INFORMAÇÔES AGENDAMENTO, e o `dgv` INSTRUMENTOS ALUGADOS teria o `ID_Agendamento` do dgv AGENDAMENTOS e também teria todos os campos que estão dentro do groupbox INSTRUMENTOS A ALUGAR, lembrando que o botão inserir insere os instrumentos no `dgv` do group box INSTRUMENTOS A ALUGAR e o botão excluir exclui os instrumentos inseridos por causa do administrador ter inserido algum instrumento errado.

Código do form-----

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using UIWINDOWS.bdtccTableAdapters;

namespace UIWINDOWS
{
    public partial class FrmAgenda3 : Form
    {
        public FrmAgenda3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void FrmAgenda3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'etecbd.Alugados' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.alugadosTableAdapter2.Fill(this.etecbd.Alugados);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'etecbd.Agenda' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.agendaTableAdapter2.Fill(this.etecbd.Agenda);


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmBuscarMusico obj = new FrmBuscarMusico();
            obj.ShowDialog();
            iD_ClIENTETextBox.Text = obj.Codreto.ToString();
            nomeTextBox.Text = obj.Nomeretor.ToString();
            iD_ClIENTETextBox.Focus();


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmBuscarInstrumento obj = new FrmBuscarInstrumento();
            obj.ShowDialog();
            codigo_instrumentoTextBox.Text = obj.Codret.ToString();           
            codigo_instrumentoTextBox.Focus();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade stackoverlow em português. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Insira o código que você já tentou.

Comment: Coloca o seu código, só com essa descrição não tem como te ajudar.